# I found a way to remove controls on a school Chromebook. How should I tell the school?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, disclosure

Our school uses [LanSchool Air](https://lanschool.com/solutions/lanschool/) and content keeper. I found a way to disable both.

I have already gotten my Chromebook taken away for "abusing Chromebook privileges" I think this is a major flaw that should be fixed.

How should I tell the school?

Comment: Were you legitimately abusing your privileges, or was the punishment an overreach?

Answer (score 0):

You should not tell the school. Depending on where you live, this can be considered malicious abuse of computer. So don't bother.

If your Chromebook has been already taken, don't even try to "anonymously" warn the school, they will know it was you. You could ask LanSchool directly if they have a bug bounty or coordinated disclosure program, and coordinate with them. If they don't have anything, you can ask for a security contact, and try to coordinate with this contact.

But be advised that sometimes contacting a company about security issues can backfire, sometimes dramatically. So I suggest that unless the company have a bug bounty or coordinated disclosure program, forget about it. You could damage your future if things go badly.

Comment: Jumped WAY too quickly onto the "don't tell the school" advice. You have no idea what the outcome could be ... Even using bug bounties could land someone in jail in some jurisdictions. So, this advice should be tempered, and equally tempered.

Comment: I've seem so many well intended researchers getting burned by 3rd party because of security. If the company isn't responsible enough to have a bug bounty or vuln disclosure program, I would not risk contacting them.

Comment: this exploit is so easy to do that's why I think its a thing that should be fixed it takes not even a minute to set up and anyone could do it with minimum knowledge of computer software